# Attempting to Disprove: If every vertex of G has degree 2, then G is a cycle

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, visualization

According to http://www.sfu.ca/~mdevos/345/homework1_sol.pdf, the statement

```
If every vertex of G has degree 2, then G is a cycle
```

is a false statement.

I have attempted to draw a counter example attached as jpeg to confirm that we have a false statement.
[image: Counterexample]

Orange dots represent vertices. Black lines are edges. $H_1$ and $H_2$ are names of the subgraphs of $G$. The union of $H_1$ and $H_2$ is graph $G$. 
Every subgraph of $G$ has vertices of degree equal to two, so every vertex of $G$ has degree 2. However, $G$ is not cyclic.

Is my counterexample correct?

Comment: Can $G$ be non connected?

Comment: @Sigur $G$ can be non-connected. $G$ must be finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is perfect.

You may also wonder on this:
Can you have a connected counterexample to this problem?

Comment: I think that if $G$ must be connected graph and every vertex of $G$ has degree $2$, then it is true that then $G$ is a cycle. Am I correct?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047426/is-every-connected-finite-undirected-graph-in-which-all-vertices-are-degree-tw?rq=1

Comment: Why is the person who answers the question never always the person who comments first?

Comment: You know why :P